# git clone doesn't work for me

Tags: git, clone

Today I am asking the question about how to clone a bare-repository which is system1's into System2 using the command "git clone `file:////192.168.1.8/c:/Users/Admin/project.git`.
Some one gives the answer which is below 
 first, assign a drive letter to a share folder:

```
net use w: \\192.168.1.8\c$

then use that local path

git clone w:\directory\project.git
# or
git clone file://w:/directory/project.git
```

But while I am trying this

```
"COMMAND:net use w: \\192.168.1.8\c$"
```

It gives the error

```
"ERROR:System error 67 has occurred.
The network name cannot be found."
```

Comment: Why not post a comment on the answer in the other question?

Answer (score 0):

C$ is admin share, and can be restricted for guest mapping.
Try to map this share from another machine, and check if it asks for a password.
If it does, your command should look like:

`net use W: \\192.168.1.8\c$ /user:username password`

I also met situation when I couldn't map using IP address, so I had to add server's IP and name to hosts file, and use "net use" command with server's name instead of IP.